# How to insert value with new increment in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
public function myfuntion() {
    if($_POST){
        $urnno = "NU-62819100";
        $data = array(
                    "name" => $this->input->post('name'),
                    "email" => $this->input->post('email'),
                    "phone" => $this->input->post('phone'),
                    "urnno" => $urnno + 1
                );
        $sql = $this->db->insert('student',$data);
        if($sql){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
    $this->loca->view('myform');
}
```

In this code I am simply insert form value but what happen here when I insert value then `urnno` must be auto increment after new insert like if when I insert value first time then `urnno` must be `NU-62819101` second time it will be `102` then `103` like this. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get the last `urnno` stored in the `table`, get its numerical part increment it and then save it in the `table`.

I've written a possible solution for your problem, comments are mentioned wherever necessary. See if it helps you.

```
public function myfuntion() {

    if($_POST){

        // get the last row saved in table
        $last = $this->db->select('urnno')->from('student')->order_by('id', 'DESC')->get()->row(); // id or some other auto incremented field

        // get urnno from the last row
        $last_urnno = $last->urnno;

        $last_arr = explode("-", $last_urnno); // make it an array to get the numerical part

        $new = $last_arr[1] + 1; // increment the value

        $urnno = "NU-{$new}"; // new value

        $data = array(
                    "name" => $this->input->post(''),
                    "email" => $this->input->post(''),
                    "phone" => $this->input->post(''),
                    "urnno" => $urnno // new value
                );

        $sql = $this->db->insert('student', $data);

        if($sql){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
    $this->loca->view('myform');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only increment the column with value 1 then you can try with setting up the column auto incremented in database. it makes easier and remove unwanted calculations.